# Delete files older than X days from multiple servers using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have scripts in both PowerShell and Batch file where in it will deleted all the files older than X days from the root folder and inside the sub folders as well from one computer, but I am looking for script where it will delete the files older than X days from multiple servers using one script.

Below is the code which I used in both PowerShell and Batch files

**PowerShell Script:**

```powershell
Clear-Host

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "30"

$TargetFolder = "C:\Older"
$Extension = "*.*"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}


foreach ($File in $Files)
  {
  if ($File -ne $NULL)
    {
      write-host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
    Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
    }
  else
    { Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -foregroundcolor "Green" }
  }
```

**Batch file:**

```powershell
ForFiles /p "C:\Older" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"

Pause
```

Answer (score 2):

For PowerShell logic to run from one location against multiple servers, ensure [Enable-PSRemoting](https://ss64.com/ps/enable-psremoting.html) is run on each of the servers you want to run commands against remotely. Once that is enabled, use [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html) to run PowerShell commands and other executable files on remote servers.

1. Ensure PSRemoting is enabled on each server by running `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` on each of the servers one time, via Group Policy or startup scripts, or however you normally do that in your environment.
2. Create a list of the servers you want to run the command against to do the cleanup either by putting an array list in the scripted logic or in a text file and using that to create an array via [get-content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html).

   > So for the server list the two options are...
   >
   > 1. Put the list of servers in the script itself `$Servers = @("Server1","Server2.domain.com","Server4.otherdomain.com");`
   > 2. Have a text file with the servers in it and use `Get-Content` in the script to get the list

### Script

```
Clear-Host
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$Servers = @("Server1","Server2.domain.com","Server4.otherdomain.com");
###$Servers = Get-Content "\\Server\Share\Folder\Lists\ServerCleanupList.txt"

$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "30"
$TargetFolder = "C:\Older"
$Extension = "*.*"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

$Servers | %{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem $Using:TargetFolder -Include $Using:Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $Using:LastWrite}
        $Files | %{If($_.FullName){$_.FullName | Remove-Item -Force}}
        C:\Windows\System32\forfiles.exe /p "C:\Older" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"
        } -AsJob;
};
```

Using `Invoke-Command` with the `-AsJob` parameter executes the command on the remote system as a background job, and then moves on doing the same for each subsequent server in the list.

### Supporting Resources

- [Enable-PSRemoting](https://ss64.com/ps/enable-psremoting.html)
- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)

  > `-ScriptBlock scriptblock`
  >
  > The commands to run.
  >
  > Enclose the commands in curly braces `{ }` to
  >   create a script block. This parameter is required.
  >
  > By default, any
  >   variables in the command are evaluated on the remote computer. To
  >   include local variables in the command, use `-ArgumentList` or in
  >   PowerShell 3.0+ *use the prefix **`$using:`** before the local variable* to be
  >   passed e.g.  `{ echo $using:mylocalVar }`
- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)

Comment: The above script which you gave is not removing the files from the folders

Comment: For the batch file is any option to get all the list of servers an d then executed the command which i have tried above

Comment: The Script is working absolutely fine as i expected, if possible can you please help me with a Batch file script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106699/discussion-between-chandu-and-pimp-juice-it).

Comment: I have used the above to for running the script on multiple servers, i had given the server name as a FQDN but still when i run the script it is deleting the files only on the server where i run the script

Comment: @chandu Well, I just confirmed I can use an array with `invoke-command` for the value of the `-ComputerName` parameter. So I guess that isn't a problem after all but I wanted to see if you have a chance to run the latest code from the loop as it was modified a couple days ago? Can you share with me the code you are using to set the array variable in your case for `$Servers =` and either the content of that code just as you are using whether file or variable with values. Share with me what you are using there. You get no error, but when run only runs on local server you run on, right?

Comment: Please share with me the full code you are using and the content of the list of servers to set the `$servers` variable if you used a file to create it.  You can use https://pastebin.com/ if you want just send me a link of what you copy and that'll be good enough to start. I just gotta see what you are seeing and using to ensure I fully understand and aren't overlooking something. I do this stuff for a living every day.